# How to find RabbitMQ connection string

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, health-check

I am trying to add HealthCheck  for [RabbitMQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Rabbitmq/).

First off.

1. Its running
2. it works I can queue things to it.

This is not an issue with RabbitMQ this is an issue with the HealthCheck connecting to RabbitMQ

I have added this to my Configure services.

```
services
    .AddHealthChecks()
    .AddRabbitMQ(rabbitConnectionString:"amqps://guest:guest@localhost/vhost");
```

But it throws an exception.

> fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.DefaultHealthCheckService[103]
> Health check rabbitmq completed after 4144.5115ms with status Unhealthy and description '(null)'
> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Obously there is something wrong with how I am building the connection string but i have tried everything I can think of.

Its not `"amqps://guest:guest@localhost/rabbit"` either

This is a dev version so the defaults are all in place.

I was wondering if it had something to do with the name in the UI

[image]

but my code that actually reads and writes from the queue use localhost so I'm not sure why localhost wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite late to reply but I had the same issue just now.

the way I fixed the issue is using the overload with `IConnection` instead of the `string` connectionstring one.

```cs
private static IConnection GetRabbitMqConnection(IServiceProvider _)
{
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.UserName = "user";
    factory.Password = "password";
    factory.VirtualHost = "/vhost";
    factory.HostName = "localhost";
    factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
    IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
}
```

and then

```
services
    .AddHealthChecks()
    .AddRabbitMQ(GetRabbitMqConnection);
```

That is giving me healthy responses.

Comment: Im pretty sure i ended up doing something like that exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Default RabbitMQ installation does not have TLS configured. So connection should be using `amqp` protocol instead of `amqps`, i.e. URI should start with `amqp://`.

See here for for more info:

- [RabbitMQ URI Specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html)
- [RabbitMQ TLS Support](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html)

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not compile, so this modified version makes it compile and run.
It gives a healthy status with fresh RabbitMQ installation (NO customization has been done at all)

```cs
using RabbitMQ.Client;

private static IConnection GetRabbitMqConnection(IServiceProvider _)
{
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        UserName = "guest",
        Password = "guest",
        HostName = "localhost",
        Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort
    };
    return factory.CreateConnection();
}
```

```cs
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddRabbitMQ((IServiceProvider provider, RabbitMQHealthCheckOptions options) =>
    {
        options.Connection = GetRabbitMqConnection(provider);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the connection string directly to health check RabbitMQ.

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddRabbitMQ(new Uri("amqp://username:password@ip:port/vhost"))
```

Just replace `username`, `password`, `ip`, `port`, `vhost` with your own specific configuration. 
Note: You can try to omit the `vhost` part completely and still the connection string will work